The python script that installs minecraft doesn't work, how to fix?
my code
import os
import subprocess
import logging 

installer_path = 'forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860-installer.jar'

forge_install_path = 'minecraft_direct' 

install_command = ['java', '-jar', installer_path, '--installClient', '--installPath', forge_install_path]
subprocess.run(install_command, check=True)
minecraft_params = ['java', '-Xmx6024M', '-jar', os.path.join(forge_install_path, 'forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860-universal.jar')]
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm Projects\TestProjects\MinecraftLauncher\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    subprocess.run(install_command, check=True)
  File "C:\Users\Sergey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-jar', 'forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860-installer.jar', '--installClient', '--installPath', 'minecraft_direct']' returned non-zero exit status 1

working directory
I've tried searching for the problem on the internet, asking chat gpt but nothing has turned up

If you run the actual command yourself in a command window, instead of trying to run it with python, the error should be displayed.

Also, just because the jar file is in the same directory as the python code file, does NOT necessarily mean the executed command can see the jar file.

I try to install from cmd, but cmd give this error
Exception in thread "main"
joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: installDir is not a recognized option
at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:519)
at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:405)
at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.main(SimpleInstaller.java:76)

how to fix python to see .jar file?

installDir is not a recognized option This code does not use an installDir option.  Why did you use a different command than the one in the code?

If you try to run the installer from CMD and it fails, why would expect a Python wrapper to solve the problem?
